# Как повысить производительность запроса?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT count(*) AS co FROM todo 
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM user_todo_send uts
        WHERE uts.id_todo = todo.id AND uts.id_user = $id_user
    ) 
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM todo_task_send ts
        WHERE ts.id_todo = todo.id AND ts.id_user_to = $id_user
    ) 
    AND todo.confirm = 1
```

Нужно получить данные с одной таблицы (`todo`), но так, чтобы ID был двух других таблицах.

Запрос работает, но `EXPLAIN` выдаёт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас много подзапросов. Лучше использовать join-ы
Что-то типа этого:

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as co 
FROM 
    todo t
left join
    user_todo_send uts on(t.id = uts.id_todo)
left join
    todo_task_send tts on(t.id = tts.id_todo)
where
    todo.confirm = 1 and
    (
        uts.id_todo is not null or 
        tts.id_todo is not null
    )
```

Comment: +1 а как сделать условие которое будет считать количество и там и там и суммировать его, так как нужно получить их сумму а не сумму уникальных

Comment: Как вариант поробуйте вот так поменять условие:  (uts.id_todo is not null or tts.id_todo is not null)